# Sequence Count - Char in String java

Tags: java, string, char, sequence, counter

I have the following assignment:
Count how many "runs" of the given character appear in the given string.
A "run" is a consecutive block of one or more occurrences of the same character. For example, if the string is "AATGGGGCCGGTTGGGGGGGGGAAGC" and the character is "G", returns 4.
**No import, '?' is allowed**
My attempt:

```
public static int charRunCount(String str, char c){
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++) {
        if ( (str.charAt (i) == str.charAt (i+1)) && str.charAt (i)==c )
            counter+=1;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

output =12,
please help fix or correct.

Comment: Why should that input return 4? The longest run appears to be "GGGGGGGGG", I assume you should save and reset the counter which you get a non-matching letter.

Comment: I suppose you want the very first occurrence of the group for the reqd. char and not the other ones. If yes, then you should break the loop after the first group ends.

Comment: Try adding something like this within the `if` block: `System.out.printf("%d, %d, %c", i, counter, str.charAt(i));` You'll then see the counter and character printed for each step of the loop. You'll quickly see what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to count the number of times a run of a particular character starts. The length of the run doesn't matter.

```
public static int charRunCount(String str, char c) {
    char last = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        // whenever a run starts.
        if (last != c && str.charAt(i) == c)
            counter++;
        last = str.charAt(i);
    }
    return counter;
}
```